# "Rename" member variables in derived classes

Tags: c++, member-variables

The question may seem a little bit weird but I'll try to contestualize a little bit the use case.

Suppose you have a generic implementation of a two-dimensional (Cartesian) field with dimensions dim1 and dim2, coordinates c1 and c2.

```cpp
struct Field2D {
  struct size_type {
     size_t dim1,dim2;
  };
  struct coordinates {
     size_t c1,c2;
  }
Field2D(size_type const & siz) : size_(siz), data(size_.dim1*size_.dim2) {}
double get(coordinates const & coords) {
  return data_[coords.c1*size_.dim2 + coords.c2];
}
//Other methods
private:
  size_type size_;
  vector<double> data_;
};
```

You want to inherit from this class but you want to be more explicit about the nature of the coordinates. For example, a field PositionVersusTime whose coordinates are "x" and "t" and dimensions "nx" and "nt", whose usage I'd like to be

```cpp
int main(){
   PositionVersusTime::size_type siz;
   siz.nx = 5;
   siz.nt = 2;
   PositionVersusTime myField(siz);
   PositionVersusTime::coordinates coords;
   coords.x = 2;
   coords.t = 0;
   auto out = myField.get(coords);
   return 0;
}
```

The reason I want to do this is that the ordering may change depending on the field (for example a TimeVersusPosition) and sometimes "forgotten" by the user. Is there a way to obtain a similar behavior? or should I simply go with getters (e.g., coords.x() = 2) ?

Comment: You might be able to add reference data members to the derived type that always refer to the base type members. But that has it's own set of problems.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux An example of such a problem would be welcome.

Comment: @Rotem I believe you will have to write your own copy/move constructors and assignment operators. Beyond that, while reference data members aren't required to increase the size of the `class`, I have never seen an implementation perform this optimization, so you'll almost certainly be bloating your `class` with these aliases. Edit : These aren't show stopping problems, but they are inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining others solutions and using inheritance and reference data members, here is my solution.

Notice slight changes to the `Field2D` variable types.

```
struct size_type{
    size_t dim1, dim2;
};

struct PositionVsTime_size_type : public size_type{
    size_t& nx = dim1;
    size_t& nt = dim2;
};

struct coordinates {
    size_t c1,c2;
};

struct PositionVsTime_coordinates : public coordinates{
    size_t& x = c1;
    size_t& t = c2;
};

struct Field2D {
    Field2D(size_type& siz) : size_(siz), data_(size_.dim1*size_.dim2) {}
    double get(coordinates& coords) {
        return data_[coords.c1*size_.dim2 + coords.c2];
    }
    Field2D& set(coordinates& coords, double val){
        data_[coords.c1*size_.dim2 + coords.c2] = val;
        return *this;
    }
    private:
    size_type& size_;
    vector<double> data_;
};

struct PositionVersusTime : public Field2D {
    PositionVersusTime(size_type& siz) : Field2D(siz) {}
};

int main(){
   PositionVsTime_size_type siz;
   siz.nx = 5;
   siz.nt = 2;
   PositionVersusTime myField(siz);
   PositionVsTime_coordinates coords;
   coords.x = 2;
   coords.t = 0;
   myField.set(coords, 5);
   auto out = myField.get(coords);
   cout << out << endl; // will print 5
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This all falls apart when the structure size_type is later moved, for example if it is stored in a std::vector, as the references in PositionVsTime_size_type become dangling references.

Answer (score 5):

No. You cannot "rename" a base class member in a derived class. That's simply not something the language allows.

A variable gets its name when it is declared and that is then its name forever. You can create aliases (references) to it if you like or you can have functions by whatever name that changes it, but the fundamental name of a variable is set in stone at declaration time.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *rename* variables in a child class, but with a little work, being able to write your `main` code is absolutely possible.

I'd start by making my own custom `coordinates` and `size_type` in the `PositionVersusTime::` scope. And then override the constructor and `get` functions in `PositionVersusTime` to take these new structs.

So your `PositionVersusTime` struct will look like:

```
struct PositionVersusTime : public Field2D {
    struct size_type { size_t nx, nt; };
    struct coordinates { size_t x, t; };
    PositionVersusTime(size_type const & siz) : Field2D({siz.nx, siz.nt}) { }
    double get(coordinates const & coords) { return Field2D::get({coords.x, coords.t}); }
};
```

Then the main code you posted will work as you expect:

```
int main() {
   PositionVersusTime::size_type siz;
   siz.nx = 5;
   siz.nt = 2;
   PositionVersusTime myField(siz);
   PositionVersusTime::coordinates coords;
   coords.x = 2;
   coords.t = 0;
   auto out = myField.get(coords);
   return 0;
}
```

See it work here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/ZpkTbZ)

Comment: Clearly this works but it requires the overloading of any method taking size_type and coordinates.. it may be long.

Comment: @Teloze it does, but the overloaded versions should all be one line (and look exactly like my overload of `get`). I suppose depending on the size of your class this may not be reasonable, but that's your call!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rename in the derived class but you can use reference to base members in the derived class

```
size_t& x = coordinates::c1;
```

However using reference will prevent reassignment because it's not possible to reassign a reference and you have to find a workaround in case of assignment.

Comment: Caveat: Because a reference cannot be reassigned, having reference members wrecks havoc on the assignment operator. You may find yourself having a to implement a custom `operator=` to get around this.

Comment: @user4581301 since the reference isn't assignable, I don't think there is a sensible way to do it even with a custom operator. They do need custom copy / move constructors. Another caveat: This unnecessarily increases size of the class.

Comment: @eerorika the way I see it here, after the assignment, the reference will still refer to the same variable. I'd just leave trying to reseat the reference out and make sure all of the non-reference variables. Thanks for bringing up the constructors. That's even sneakier since there likely won't be any diagnostic warning that with the default copy/move constructor the copy is referring to the source's variables. Nasty, nasty surprise.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments here, the solution with references in derived classes can be problematic, as it introduces the possibility of creating dangling references.
You want to avoid that.

Instead of doing:

```
struct size_type{
    size_t dim1;
};

struct PositionVsTime_size_type : public size_type{
    size_t& nx = dim1;
};
```

simply do:

```
#define nx dim1

struct size_type{
    size_t dim1;
};

struct PositionVsTime_size_type : public size_type{
};
```

Now the compiler substitutes *dim1* for each occurrence of a token *nx* in the source file.

*nx* is not replaced if it does not form a token - appears in a comment, in a string, or is as part of a longer identifier.

Comment: ... and it also substitutes it everywhere else